# Is there a way to run both firebase-tools v2 and v3 at the same time?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I have some firebase apps using SDK v3 and some still on SDK v2. I have to keep switching between the two versions of firebase-tools in order to deploy the apps to firebase hosting. Is there a way to run both versions of the CLI at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've switched to using the 3.x version of Firebase tools as my global version: `npm install firebase-tools -g`.

Then for my legacy projects, I now keep the firebase-tools version in the local directory, so `npm install firebase-tools@2.2.1`. You might have to run it with `node_modules/firebase-tools/bin/firebase` in that case, since the global version takes precedence.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, Frank. So when you are in the older 2.x version project, how do you run the legacy "firebase" CLI. I installed it locally, but `firebase -V` returns 3.0.2

Comment: Added one way of doing that.